# PDF on TransformedDistribution of two BinomialDistribution too slow

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I'd been doing my own convolutions of distributions for some calculations, decided to use built-ins.

With

```
p5 = TransformedDistribution[py + pz, 
  {Distributed[py, BinomialDistribution[7, .2]], 
   Distributed[pz, BinomialDistribution[7, .3]]}]

PDF[p5, 5]
```

getting the PDF takes an inordinate amount of time (as in 30+ seconds on the laptop I'm on at the moment, faster on my real machines of course, but still slow.)

I'm guessing it is using `DiscreteConvolve` under the covers, which is itself inordinately slow IMO, but I'm pondering if I'm missing something obvious in the use of `TransformedDistribution`.

Any ideas (or explanations) for the slowness appreciated.

Comment: On my 64-bit Windows 7 machine this takes about .7 seconds for version 8.0.4 and 9.0.1.  What system are you using?

Comment: PDF[p5, 5] takes 2.4 seconds on my rather elderly iMac.

Comment: @Andy & m_goldberg: There was a typo in original example, argument to PDF I used was 5, rather than 2. I am on 9.0.1, but as I said timing was on a crippled laptop, it is a few seconds on my normal machines, but that still seems awfully low. I'm getting the feeling though that this is just a slow operation, and for real work I'm better off doing explicit optimized convolutions of the individual PDFs. Btw, thanks for cleaning up post if one of you did it...

Comment: My timings didn't change by using 5 instead of 2. That said, I'm on a machine with 32GB memory with a fairly fast (4.3GHz) cpu.

Comment: Read my comment again. I tested with PDF[p5, 5].

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I ran it on a mathcluster and it flies, looking under the covers it creates (as expected) a piecewise function by sum for tuples of each possible combination of m summing to n for each n in PDF[dist,n], so it just needs horsepower. I'll update as answered when I can (limited as new user).

Answer (score 1):

Looking under the covers it creates (as expected) a piecewise function by sum for tuples of each possible combination of m summing to n for each n in PDF[dist,n], so it just needs horsepower.